# Postgres data set ETL

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, etl

I'm extracting data from a MS SQL Server database into my Postgres database every 30 min.

This task is made more complex due to the fact that the data in the SQL Server database is very non-relational. It comes from an old schemaless database and it's not properly indexed.

What I would like to do is every time I pull the data from SQL Server, I would compare that dataset with the existing one in the Postgres database. Then I would like to get only the difference and then `UPDATE` Postgres instead of recreating all data from the SQL Server.

Postgres is a cloud based database and the SQL Server is a local DB. If I try (and I did try) to rebuild the entire Postgres DB it will easily blow my 30 min. window.

I tried to just push the entire DB from local to cloud and rebuild the DB in Postgres. This took way over 30 minutes.

I was also able to do a diff between the 2 data dumps.

The question is: How can I do check for a delta/diff between 2 data dumps and extract only the delta?

EDIT: Added question relevant to what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but have you considered using SSIS for this purpose? It _is_, after all, an ETL engine.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. You are wanting to delta enable your ETL, but it is a very ETL-Tool and Data specific solution that you will end up with, which is both too broad for SO, and unclear.

Comment: @mustaccio I did think of that but I the ms-sql server is out of reach and I only get the data through ODBC connector

Comment: Doesn't prevent you from setting up SSIS locally, if you have the license.

Comment: If you keep a local copy of Postgres as a SQL Server database (name it SHDb), then you can always compare your live db using SMO (SQL Server Management Object). I think it can generate INSER/UPDATE/DELETE script. That script can be run on Postgres and if Successful, run it on SHDb as well to sync your local copy with the Postgres on cloud. this process lets you keep all 3 dbs in sync. I think this way you won't have performance issue

Comment: Are you trying to load data into postgres from a flat file or other data dump? Or are you connecting through a Foreign Data Wrapper?  If the latter, then it is fairly easy to left join the sql-server data to the postgres data to identify which rows don't exist yet, do exist but are identical, or do exist but have changes. Then update or insert as appropriate.